# Reverse "make duplicates real"

Tags: modeling

Currently we have the operation “Make duplicates real”… I was wondering if there was the reverse of that operation “Make real objects duplicate” or something, turning objects into empties, keeping all transforms?

I know this could be somewhat achieved via dupli{verts,faces} or via particles or particle instance modifier, however I was looking for an operation that didn’t involve all those.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: ctrl L > Make Links > Object Data?

Comment: I've added an image to further illustrate what I mean... I need the objects to be converted into empties.

Comment: ok so ctrl L doesn't seem to work in your case

Comment: Yes. Right now I'm using the add-on copy attributes to copy location/rotation/scale but it only works on one object at a time. Doing that for a thousand objects is extremely time consuming.

Comment: what do you mean when you say it only works on one object at a time? Actually you can select several objects and the last selected will be the one you'll copy. That said, it doesn't seem to allow you to transform meshes to empties.

Comment: Yes, but selecting several empties and then selecting a reference object (last selected; active) would copy attributes of that object only. To do something like in the crop shot, I need to select an empty, select an object next, then ctrl-c > copy location> ctrl-c > copy rotation> ctrl-c > copy scale. Repeat for each object.

Perhaps the better question would be "how to place empties in each object's origin, with all transformations of the individual object copied?"

Comment: It seems like you're requesting a new scripting add-on? The task you mentioned may not be easy to do in Blender without a suitable add-on.